# Excel SUMIFS compare ranges

Tags: excel, sumifs

I want to sum up a value from all cells in column H, where the value in K is bigger than the value in F. I thought I could do this like that:

=SUMIFS(Gains!H:H;Gains!E:E;"sold";Gains!K:K;">="&Gains!F:F)

But the last criterion is problematic:

Gains!K:K;">="&Gains!F:F

How can I express this correctly?

Comment: What version of excel do you use?

Comment: You didn't mention column E

Comment: now i mentioned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer versions `=SUM(H:H*(K:K>=F:F)*(E:E="sold"))`

if all these cells are in `Gains` sheet, could rewrite:

`=SUM(Gains!H:H*(Gains!K:K>=Gains!F:F)*(Gains!E:E="sold"))`

Comment: Which version of excel do you use?

Comment: Yes there was a semicolon instead of equal sign

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job (adjust ranges to whole column)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Gains!$E$1:$E$30="sold")*(Gains!$K$1:$K$30>=Gains!$F$1:$F$30)*($H$1:$H$30))
```